# Linking custom boost with CMake

Tags: boost, cmake, dynamic-linking

I have boost 1.53 which was installed by yum. But I need to built my application required boost version 1.64. So I built boost 1.64 and installed with prefix `/usr/local`. The boost version detected by CMake is `1.64` (shown is message generated by CMake). But when I use `ldd` to check, its is version `1.53`

I tried to reproduce the problem by create a small project and create a simple boost test linking to `Boost::unit_test_framework`. But it linking to the correct Boost version. When I looking in to link.txt of the executable, I saw that line:

```
c++ -g main.cpp.o -o Test -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
```

But in my main projects, it was

```
c++ -g -o ......  -lnsl -lrt -lboost_program_option -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread
```

I check `ld` search path by this command:

```
$ gcc -m64 -Xlinker --verbose  2>/dev/null | grep SEARCH | sed 's/SEARCH_DIR("=\?\([^"]\+\)"); */\1\n/g'  | grep -vE '^$'
```

and the result is:

```
/usr/local/lib64
/lib64
/usr/lib64
/usr/local/lib
......
```

The boost 1.53 install path is `/lib64` and the install path of 1.64 is `/usr/local/lib`. So I think the test version is correct because of boost's absolute path is specified. And if the absolute path is not specified, `ld` will use version 1.53 because it was located first.

I tried set BOOT_ROOT and Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS but can't solve this problem.

**Update:** I found the problem. The original cmake file was look like this:

```
find_package(Boost 1.64 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
target_link_library(MyProgram PRIVATE Boost::program_options) #original cmake
#target_link_library(MyProgram PRIVATE boost_program_options) #my cmake
#target_link_library(MyProgram PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) #fixed cmake
```

I fix the cmake because I can not run `cmake` with *original cmake*. `cmake` told me that `Boost:program_options` was not found on my computer. When I replace with `boost_program_options`, then it work but this library is not result of `find_package`.

Comment: Without viewing the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) it is difficult to find a reason.

Comment: Maybe your LD_LIBRARIES_PATH contains /usr/local after /usr ?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I can't  because of security reason, my company does not allow me to leak the code. 

@ arved LD_LIBRARIES_PATH is empty

Comment: No needs to show the **whole** your code. Prepare [mcve] - the small code, which reproduces you problem (check that!), - and add that code to the question post, so we can check it too. Do you run `ldd` on the application which is just *built* (after `make`) or which is *installed* (after `make install`)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I run `ldd` on the application which is just built. And I updated the question.

Comment: As far as I know, CMake (or linker?) never incorporates full path to the dependent library into the ELF file, it always use a library name. Your executable has the first RPATH equal to `/usr/local/lib64`. Probably, some other library, linked into your executable, is located under this directory. BTW, CMake should emit a warning when a wrong library could be found because of RPATH settings.

Comment: Thank you, I found the way to fix it. But I don't know why I can not use `Boost::program_options` in cmake.